# Is there a method to check the given document root directory exists in Apache2 virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I want to check the root directory exists or not in Apache2 virtual host. If it doesn't exist I want to point the virtual host to a default directory. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It should work can you try?

```
<If "-d /var/www/html">
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</If>
<Else>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html2"
</Else>
```

Comment: This shouldn't work, and indeed doesn't. `<If>` introduces a “directory” context, and `DocumentRoot` can only exist in “server config” or “virtual host” context.